# Logitech Setpoint Keystroke assignment

Tags: logitech

With the m570 Logitech mouse, I've been trying to setup a "Keystroke Assignment" that would send in the keystrokes Shift + Windows Key + Right arrow.

I've found this post https://superuser.com/questions/947869/windows-10-virtual-desktop-hotkeys post which references another post about how to update the user.xml page to do that here - https://tinkertry.com/logitech-multiple-desktop-mouse-mappings-for-windows-10.

I've updated the forward "4" button to have this below. However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any ideas how to get this working?

```
<Button Number="5" Name="4">
               <Param IconLoc="" Type=""/>
               <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
                  <Param Button="5" EventType="100663297" FirstRepeatDelay="0" RepeatDelay="0" Silent="0" Type="0"/>
                  <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="KeystrokeAssignment">
                     <Handler Class="KeyStroke">
                        <Param KeyName="{SHIFT}*{RIGHT}"/>
                    </Handler>  
                  </TriggerState>
               </Trigger>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Add the language tag

Comment: This can be done from Lua script in GHub.  Use `PressKey` and `ReleaseKey` functions.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone who has a similar issue, I couldn't get Logitech's software to do what I needed. I ended up using AutoHotKey where I created an .ahk file with this code below.

XButton2::SendEvent +#{Right}

It should be noted that SendEvent is important as Send had a habit of causing the Windows Key to be stuck.